# Rss feed not showing date?

Tags: php, rss

In my rss feed that shows the title,link,pubDate and description in chrome browser.

But in firefox it onlly shows the title and description..

in page source of firefox rss feed it having all the tags like title,link,description and pubDate. but date not showing what can i do?..

my rss code like,

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>
Subscribe now
</title>
<description>desc</description>
<link>site link</link>
<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>
<item>
<title>title1
</title>
<link>
link1
</link>
<pubDate>2012-10-26 19:18:36</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
<title>title2
</title>
<link>
link2
</link>
<pubDate>2012-10-26 19:15:24</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your format isn't correct. Here is an article of how the format should look http://tomchikoore.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/correct-rss-date-format/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RSS 2.0 spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html):

> All date-times in RSS conform to the Date and Time Specification of
>   [RFC 822](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html), with the exception that the year may be expressed with two
>   characters or four characters (four preferred).

... and the following example is provided:

```
Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT
```